# How to make a custom menu on PHP?

Tags: php, html, menu, hyperlink

I am new to PHP, however, I have developed a membership frameworks for my website that is fully functional. There is one thing I would like to do before I begin designing, but I don't know how. I will provide my code so that I can use examples:

HTML/PHP

```
 <div id="Top">

<div id="Menubar">

    <a href="http://www.codesrce.com">Home</a>

    <?php
    if($_SESSION['loggedin'] = false){
        echo '<a href="http://www.codesrce.com/signup.php">Sign Up</a><a href="http://www.codesrce.com/signin.php">Sign In</a>';
        exit();
    }else if($_SESSION['loggedin'] = true){
        echo '<a href="http://www.codesrce.com/signout.php">Sign Out</a>';
        exit();
    }
    ?>          
</div>

</div>
```

As you can see, So far I have a simple, mediocre menu in place. What I am looking to do is to make it respond to my PHP script, which I don't know how to properly structure. In my frameworks, when a user logs in, their $_SESSION['loggedin'] value is changed to true, and when they log out, the value is changed to false. So what I am looking for is to have my menu show only the appropriate hyperlinks for the user. For example, if a user is signed in, they don't want hyperlinks that will lead them to sign in or sign up, they will want the hyperlink to sign out. And when a user is not signed in and/or does not have an account, they will want the hyperlinks to sign in and sign up. My PHP above currently does not work. Is there any way to do what I am looking for? If so, please help! Thanks in advance!

Here is the Signin.php

```
<?php
// AJAX CALLS THIS LOGIN CODE TO EXECUTE
if(isset($_POST["e"])){
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
// GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES AND SANITIZE
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
$p = md5($_POST['p']);
// GET USER IP ADDRESS
$ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
// FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
if($e == "" || $p == ""){
    echo "signin_failed";
    exit();
} else {
// END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $db_id = $row[0];
    $db_username = $row[1];
    $db_pass_str = $row[2];
    if($p != $db_pass_str){
        echo "signin_failed";
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "false";
        exit();
    } else {
        // CREATE THEIR SESSIONS AND COOKIES
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";
        setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
        setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
        setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE); 
        // UPDATE THEIR "IP" AND "LASTLOGIN" FIELDS
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET ip='$ip', lastlogin=now() WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        echo $db_username;
        exit();
    }
}
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Have you tried echoing the value of $_SESSION['loggedin'] to make sure it is being set correctly when they log in?

Comment: Here is a link to my site (http://www.codesrce.com) and Unless my IP is already signed in, you will also see on your computer that the menu just says "Home" and "Sign Out" when you are not even signed in @BarbaraLaird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change = to ==. You're comparing, not assigning. Also, no need to put `exit()` *because it will terminate the next operations*, just what EternalHour said to his post that it will end the next echo.

```
  <?php
        if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == false){
            echo '<a href="http://www.codesrce.com/signup.php">Sign Up</a><a href="http://www.codesrce.com/signin.php">Sign In</a>';
            //exit();
        }else if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            echo '<a href="http://www.codesrce.com/signout.php">Sign Out</a>';
           // exit();
        }
        ?>
```

**EDIT**

Add [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in your sign_up or sign_in code to address $_SESSION.

```
// END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    session_start();
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
```

Comment: For some reason, it only works for the not logged in feature. Maybe the else if statement is not allowing the logged in one to work?

Comment: When I am not logged on it displays only the Sign Up and Sign In hyperlinks, which is what I want, but when I am signed in, it still shows those 2, not the Sign Out hyperlink, which is what i want, for some reason @kimbarcelona

Comment: The first condition is if $_SESSION['loggedin'] is not set. If you set $_SESSION['loggedin'] upon sign in or sign up, else if will work.

Comment: Have you put value in $_SESSION['loggedin'] after sign in or sign up? It's like $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";

Comment: The Signin.php is what goes off when the user tries to sign in @kimbarcelona

Comment: That wasn't a solution @EternalHour

Comment: @EternalHour, sorry if my answer seems to have your answer as well but I've modified it i think after you've answered as well

Comment: Hi @user3761911, you need to add session_start(). See my edit

Comment: @user3761911 It wasn't a solution? "Okay the removing of the exit worked. Thanks :)"

Comment: My apologies, I just meant that it reminded me that I didn't need that. I should have reworded. English isn't my first language. @EternalHour

Comment: Well, it was not solution fully because it need session_start(); also. But I can't downvote because I don't have reputation of 15. Thank you for part of the solution. And don't feel bad. My site is just a silly old simple website that isn't going anywhere. @EternalHour It is just for educational purposes

Comment: Well, stackoverflow has edit functionality to modify the answer. Shame on you for being so rude for just an answer. You're greatly affected with this thinking that your answer solves OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

A bit cleaner code as an example where you also check that the session is set:

```
<?php
$notLoggedInMenu = '<a href="http://www.codesrce.com/signup.php">Sign Up</a><a href="http://www.codesrce.com/signin.php">Sign In</a>';
$loggedInMenu = '<a href="http://www.codesrce.com/signout.php">Sign Out</a>';
echo isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] ? $loggedInMenu : $notLoggedInMenu;
?>
```

Comment: You'll always need to check if the session is set. Otherwise you might get a warning. It doesn't matter what values you use for the session.

Comment: This is better. Once I get it to work, I might use this. Thanks!

Comment: Remember to use session_start() at the top of your page. Can't find it in your example.

Answer (score -1):

I see a couple of things that may be causing issues.

First of all, as @kimbarcelona mentioned, you need to use the `==` comparison operator instead of `=`.

Secondly, you need to remove the `exit();` because that will kill your echo.

Comment: Nope. This is not a complete solution @EternalHour.

Comment: Hmm, I'll just mention you on my post

Comment: You know @EternalHour, your second answer regarding exit() is saying like it will disallow echo to work. In his code, echo was executed first before exit. It's not that clear. My answer simply says that exit will terminate next operations not only echo. It will end the execution of PHP itself. You're lack of reasoning mate.